# Bucles for and while

Tags: kotlin, do-while

I am trying to remove the name from a list but nothing, it comes out with everything inside and I just want you to tell me matematicas only and the other subjects that I will add

```
{
    "id": 419704,
    "page": 1,
    "total_results": 0,
    "total_pages": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nom_prof": "nombre profesor",
            "asignaturas": [
                {
                    "matematicas": {
                        "lunes": {
                            "hora1": "x",
                            "hora2": "x",continue....
```

and this is what I can think of

```
  clasigicacion.asignaturas.forEach {
   itemView.tv_asignaturas.text = it.toString()
```

}

clasificacion is the list

This is the adapter to make things look better

```
class TeachAdapter (val profesores: ArrayList<Results.Profesores>): androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<TeachAdapter.ClasiViewHolder>() {

private var context: Context? = null

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ClasiViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val itemClasi = profesores[position]
    holder.bindClasificacion(itemClasi)

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{

        //Toast.makeText(context, "settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("nom_prof", itemClasi?.nom_prof)
        bundle.putString("img_profe", itemClasi?.img_profe)
        bundle.putString("img_fondo", itemClasi?.img_fondo)
        bundle.putString("asignatura", itemClasi.asignaturas[0].nom_asignatura)
        bundle.putString("lunes_1", itemClasi.asignaturas[0].lunes?.hora1)
        bundle.putString("lunes_2", itemClasi.asignaturas[0].lunes?.hora2)
        bundle.putString("lunes_3", itemClasi.asignaturas[0].lunes?.hora3)
        bundle.putString("lunes_4", itemClasi.asignaturas[0].lunes?.hora4)
        bundle.putString("lunes_5", itemClasi.asignaturas[0].lunes?.hora5)
        bundle.putString("lunes_6", itemClasi.asignaturas[0].lunes?.hora6)
        context!!.startActivity(Intent(context, DetProfesor::class.java).putExtras(bundle))
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return profesores.size
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ClasiViewHolder {
   val layoutInflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
           .inflate(R.layout.teach_row, parent, false)

    context = parent.context

    return ClasiViewHolder(layoutInflate)
}

class ClasiViewHolder(itemView: View): androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "LogNotTimber")
    fun bindClasificacion(profesores: Results.Profesores){

        Picasso.get()
            .load(Constants.URL_IMAGES + profesores.img_profe)
            .resize(50, 50)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(itemView.civ_imageProf)

        //Log.d("Tag xxx: ", clasigicacion.nom_prof)

        itemView.tv_namProf.text = profesores.nom_prof

        itemView.tv_asignaturas.text = profesores.asignaturas[0].nom_asignatura

        for ((k, v) in profesores.asignaturas) {

                println("key: $k  values - $v")
        }
    }
}
```

}

The fragment from here the parser

```
class FragProfesores : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teach_list, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 1)
        recyclerView.adapter = null

        val progressBar: ProgressBar = this.progressBar

        Thread(Runnable {
            activity!!.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            })

            try {
                var i = 0
                while(i<Int.MAX_VALUE){
                    i++
                }
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            activity!!.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            })
        }).start()

        val apiClasi = Api000.getClient.getClasificacion()

        apiClasi.enqueue(object : Callback<Results> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Results>, t: Throwable?) {
               // Log.e("TAG Fallo: ", t.toString())
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Results>, response: Response<Results>) {
                for(res in response.body()!!.results){
                    //Log.d("TAG Respuesta: ", res.asignaturas!!.asig_1)
                }

                recyclerView.adapter = TeachAdapter(response.body()!!.results)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And the ModelBeen

```
data class Results (val results: ArrayList<Profesores>){

    data class Profesores (
        val id: String,
        val nom_prof: String,
        val asignaturas: ArrayList<Asignaturas>,
        val img_profe: String,
        val img_fondo: String){

        data class Asignaturas(val matematicas: Matematicas?){
            data class Matematicas(val lunes: Lunes?,val martes: Martes?){
                data class Lunes(
                    val hora1: String,val hora2: String,val hora3: String,val hora4: String,val hora5: String,val hora6: String)
                data class Martes(
                    val hora1: String,val hora2: String,val hora3: String,val hora4: String,val hora5: String,val hora6: String)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Need clarification. What name are you trying to remove? Are you working with JSON or an actual List? What does `itemView` have to do with anything here? "Bucles"? etc.

Comment: yes is aJson - 
I just want him to show me matematicas - only matematicas - how can I do it? loops?

Comment: pos 1 edited whith the adapter

Comment: Could you also include Results.Profesores ?

Comment: pos 1 edited whith the Fragment and modelBeen

Answer (score 1):

Matematicas is a key of your json, not a value. You use it to map the values into asignaturas.matematicas you may need to reconsider your data model in case you want to make the name of the subject a value.
Something like this should work:

```
{
  "asignaturas": [
    {
      "nombre": "matematicas",
      "lunes": {
        "hora1": "x",
        "hora2": "x",
        continue....
      }
    },
    {
      "nombre": "other",
      "lunes": {
        "hora1": "x",
        "hora2": "x",
        continue....
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And your data class would be:

```
data class Results(val results: ArrayList<Profesores>) {

    data class Profesores(
        val id: String,
        val nom_prof: String,
        val asignaturas: ArrayList<Asignaturas>,
        val img_profe: String,
        val img_fondo: String
    ) {

        data class Asignaturas(val nombre: String, val lunes: Dia?, val martes: Dia?) {
            data class Dia(
                val hora1: String,
                val hora2: String,
                val hora3: String,
                val hora4: String,
                val hora5: String,
                val hora6: String
            )
        }
    }
}
```